# Gradle set to daemon project base

Tags: java, gradle

I am using gradle 6.3 and java 11.

When I run the gradle project see the following lines:

```
Project base dir set to: /Users/ranjith/.gradle/daemon/6.1
```

And the checkstyle plugin is pointing to the base directory of the project:

```
 <module name="SuppressionFilter">
        <property name="file" value=".mycmp/config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml"/>
    </module>
```

I see the following error when I run the project:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/Users/ranjith/.gradle/daemon/6.3/.mycmp/config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml
```

The same works with java 8 though.

Comment: Could you please share whole checkstyle config

Comment: @AliakseiStadnik The issue is this line: 
Project base dir set to: /Users/ranjith/.gradle/daemon/6.1
Why is project base dir set to gradle daemon. It doesnt happen when I run with java 8 or java 9 and the project base dir is correctly set to the current directory where build.gradle is.

Answer (score 0):

JDK 11 expects full path. The issue is described here https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8286#issuecomment-456940831